# How to fix shorted microwave?

Tags: microwave-oven

I have a [GE Profile PVM9005SJSS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B012HL6SN2) microwave oven. It worked fine for 2 years but now it is tripping the circuit breaker whenever I turn it on. I have tried plugging it into different outlets with same result so I think the microwave has a short circuit in it somewhere. Wondering if anyone can help/guide how to fix it?

Comment: Go to store or thrift store or craigslist, buy a new (or working used) one. Dispose of the broken one. A working used one is almost always cheaper than attempting to repair.

Comment: Agreed with @Ecnerwal in this case.  Things like dryers and dishwashers can be worth repairing, but microwaves have high voltage RF electronics inside, and aren't very serviceable at home unless you really know what you're doing.  I'm an electrical engineer and I wouldn't do it myself.

Comment: I agree with @NateS. and Ecnerwal on this.  I took one apart  to use the transformer to make a spot welder. I'm an electrical engineer too and I didn't recognize half the stuff in there. Even if you could determine the problem, good luck getting parts.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the tips.

Comment: With out a background in electronics very few would be able to find the problem, also there are hazardous voltages in the cabinet yes even unplugged, if the magnetron is bad in many cases it may cost as much as an inexpensive unit and is the power supply still good. I have a degree in electronics and usually end up saving the magnet they are the strongest you can find other than disk drives.

Comment: You guys above are EE's and you don't know the simple parts inside a microwave?  Power Transformer, Magnetron, and control circuit?  While inexpensive microwaves are not worth fixing, some microwaves can be very expensive, and the one OP has me be custom built into his cabinetry...

Comment: @Hitek  This isn't  an expensive microwave and it's a fairly common size. You have no idea what parts we know  and don't know. If you're here to try and insult people, go somewhere else.

Comment: @JACK its a $440 microwave and you are saying it isn't expensive! What is your definition of an expensive microwave?

Comment: @JACK - In the US, inexpensive microwaves can be purchased brand new for around $40, while this microwave costs 10x that amount...

Comment: @morpheus  $1300-1500. I'm not debating the price, I'm debating  the fact that it would probably be too expensive to have it fixed even if you could.

Comment: It's an appliance repair question, which is off-topic here, and what's more, it's the *typical* appliance repair question: with no advance research or effort, even a rudimentary teardown to look for obvious physical damage. These invite bad answers: drive-bys, blind guesses, "hire a professional" or someone *writing a book* on every possibility.

Comment: @Hitek   My opinion is that it would be hard to find someone who could fix it. Usually when something like this shorts out, multiple  times, it takes more than one part out and would be expensive to fix.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because appliance repair is not in-scope here.  Unfortunately it's not really in-scope on other SE sites, except possibly ee.se *sometimes*. I would ask in their chat once you have a specific enough question.

Comment: That regrettably said, I would pursue warranty, home warranty, homeowners insurance etc. paths to exhaustion before tearing it off the wall for a DIY inspection or hauling it to a repair shop. But Jack's not wrong; you could *easily* get $100 of troubleshooting into it and find the unit needs a $200 hoozit.

Comment: @JACK - It still wouldn't hurt to check around.  I live in a small rural US town with a population of about 3000 people, and there are at least 3 people here who repair microwaves(one is an AC/Heat guy), likely for less than $100 labor.  If the problem was simple, like a shorted rectifier diode, it would be well worth it to get it repaired.

Comment: @Hitek  Yes, definitely check around.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - This question would be closed immediately at EE.SE as "Off-Topic" due to the fact that it is asking for repair assistance without prior troubleshooting and/or a basic understanding of the circuits involved...

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica -   You are correct in the "sometimes" part, because if the OP had some understanding of the circuits involved, and had done some troubleshooting, and then got stuck in a particular diagnosis, then the question would be on topic at EE.SE....

Answer (score 1):

Your microwave likely has a shorted transformer, magnetron, or rectifier diode, and should be repaired by an appliance technician if it is expensive enough to justify the cost.  If it is inexpensive, then not only can it be replaced cheaply, but repair parts for inexpensive microwaves are likely not available in the first place.

Comment: Most of the ones I have worked on had magnatron or power supply problems rarely do the transformers them selves go bad but the diodes and fuses do fail when the “tube” or magnatron fails or is shorted because of a reflection back into the the tube (normally caused by metal). Of these I have fixed a few but the tube itself is harder to get as transformers are usually easy to second source. After reading your comment I felt this was worth a down vote. This site is not for ripping others comments, I explained what I had said in a comment then noticed additional comments.-

Comment: You didn't like my comment under the question, so you downvoted my answer?  That doesn't make any sense, as the proper course of action for a comment you don't like would be to downvote the comment itself.   Anyhow, I did forget about the newer high-frequency switching microwaves that would have rectifier diodes near the mains, so I have updated my answer.

Comment: The root problem is the question itself has serious issues; appliance repair questions are off-topic for reasons. That makes the discussion and answers *fruit of a poisoned tree:* impossible to be good. The first 3 comments erred by presuming "cheap", but your comment was out of line.  Separately, your answer doesn't work because a) the question can't be answered well, b) it's a "Hire a Professional" answer, and c) because of a) it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - I agree with everything you said.  Sometimes it takes me some time adjusting to the style of an SE that I don't often visit.  I don't mind deleting the answer if it is the appropriate thing to do....

Comment: @Hitek Acknowledged. I have a feeling the question will be closed, so I'm not sure what to advise to do.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - I guess I will leave it up for now, as although it doesn't answer how to repair the microwave, I feel that the answer is still good advice for those that might see the question after it is closed.  Erring on the side of caution, I wouldn't say it's too large of a leap to assume that if a person needs advice on how to start troubleshooting an appliance, then that person doesn't have a basic understanding of electrical troubleshooting. In that case, learning to troubleshoot on a high-voltage microwave is a dangerous place to start, so a professional should be consulted.

Comment: I did not like the answer but at first did not down vote as I said, but after reading the comment and there have been some from others, this is not what the site is about as I also said. We try to help.